# How do I get neo4j nodes based on schema index?

Tags: neo4j, neography

I am using the ruby gem `neography`

I created a schema index based on a label `Client` and a key name `client_name`

I would want to get the node for `client_name => "some name"`

How can I get the node based on the schema index and the client_name as key. Not to search which can return more than one, but to specify the key/value pair as above?

Comment: MATCH (n:CLIENT {client_name:"some name"}) return (n) - why wouldn't running this query solve your problem?

Comment: Is it indexed this way?

Comment: yep, for sure. you can check by running PROFILE on the query. you should see 2 db hits on the node Client, even if you have 100k nodes.